Who publishes the definition of the shape of a national airspace?
Title says it all.
Who is in charge of providing/defining the official shape of a national airspace?
I guess that most of the times they follow international borders, but there must be a document somewhere stating it, right?
Also, what happens at fractal-like/oddly shaped borders?
See for example the border between Germany and Belgium near Rötgen/Monschau: is the German airspace cut by a sliver of Belgian airspace?
If not, where's the document that says so?

In short: ICAO, a UN agency, is responsible for organizing, with States and Air navigation service provider (ANSP), the global airspace, which is published in the Global Air Navigation Plan.
The global airspace is divided in Regions (FIR) defined according to national borders, as agreed in international treaties, with sensible technical adjustments. A GIS application is available to view all FIR and their boundaries. For the region at Belgium/Germany border:

The formal delineation of the European airspace is found in a Regional Air Navigation Plan: EUR Air Navigation Plan volume 1 (August 2024). Unfortunately the document is missing the actual boundary points for Brussels FIR (EBBU, “To be incorporated”), but Langen (EDGG) points are available. Europe FIR delineation is also available at Eurocontrol (Eurocontrol is the ANSP for several FIR in Europe).

Principles
Airspace delineation follow two principles:

States sovereignty over their national territory

Agreements under ICAO (a UN agency) auspices between regional ANSP.


Sovereignty is stated in article 1 of ICAO Convention on civil aviation (Chicago convention):

The contracting States recognize that every State has complete and exclusive sovereignty over the airspace above its territory.

ANSP agreements are recommended in ICAO Annex 11:

2.11.1 Recommendation.— The delineation of airspace, wherein air traffic services are to be provided, should be related to the nature of the route structure and the need for efficient service rather than to national boundaries.


Note 1.— Agreements to permit the delineation of airspace lying across national boundaries are advisable when such action will facilitate the provision of air traffic services (see 2.1.1). Agreements which permit delineation of airspace boundaries by straight lines will, for example, be most convenient where data processing techniques are used by air traffic
services units.

Flight information regions (FIR)
Global airspace is divided, according to ICAO Annex 11 §2.1.1 Establishment of authority into flight information regions (FIR). FIR over high sea waters (international waters) are said oceanic FIR. FIR are grouped into 9 Global navigation plan regions.
FIR definition by ICAO:

An airspace of defined dimensions within which flight information service and alerting service are provided.

FIR above national territories are usually controlled by a national ANSP (or delegated by a State to another State). Oceanic FIR above international waters, where this is no State jurisdiction, have their control delegated by ICAO to one State, e.g. the north Atlantic ocean is covered by several oceanic FIR delegated to US (New York Eastbound, KZWY), Canada (Gander, CZQX), Ireland (Shanwick, EGGX), Portugal (Santa Maria, LPPO) and Norway (Bodo, ENOB).
Sometimes there is no agreement on a national border, and no FIR can be set for a small area, this is known as a NO-FIR area. E.g. see Why is there a strip of uncontrolled airspace between Russia and Norway?
When possible, especially over high sea areas, FIR and Search and Rescue regions are also made coincident.

Worse than the NO-FIR situation is squabbling over control of airspace, like over Cyprus in the Nicosia FIR where ICAO recognizes FIR boundaries but the Turkish Cypriots don't recognize them and established their own conflicting boundaries. This results in conflicting instructions and lack of coordination between sectors. IFALPA has published guidance for pilots on how to deal with this, but obviously this is not a great situation for safety.


Who is in charge of providing/defining the official shape of a national airspace?

NGA (National Geospatial-Intelligence Agency) maintains an Esri/ArcGIS compatible Shapefile to distribute to DoD vendors.

Also, what happens at fractal-like/oddly shaped borders?

Software vendors make their own decision with customer input on how to handle oddly shaped borders. For example, avionics for one aircraft manufacturer may only support a certain number of polygon vertices on screen at once, so a "smoothing" algorithm is run on the raw data to cut it down to a loadable size. Certain parameters are taken into account to make sure the simplified border is always on one side of the border and never crosses into the adjacent border, so by running this algorithm against two adjacent borders, you can get a "no-man's land" in the middle where you can instruct flight crews to simply avoid flying in.

I've fixed it now, but in general, please remember to use quotes when you're quoting, not codeblocks. codeblocks are not screenreader-friendly in such a scenario

that said, I don't care about software vendors, I'm interested in the official definition.

Sorry for the additional information. The top part still stands true, though the actual data may be restricted if you're not part of the industry. My employer has access so I get the periodic drop as part of my role.

It's officially recognized international agreement-based data, there's no need to be part of any industry to be able to access it, it would kinda defeat the purpose.
